# PHP Array Loop - trying to get the array within the array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to loop the following array:

```
{
    "makerCommission": 10,
    "takerCommission": 10,
    "buyerCommission": 0,
    "sellerCommission": 0,
    "canTrade": true,
    "canWithdraw": true,
    "canDeposit": true,
    "updateTime": 1611210805740,
    "accountType": "MARGIN",
    "balances": [{
        "asset": "BTC",
        "free": "0.00000000",
        "locked": "0.00000000"
    }, {
        "asset": "LTC",
        "free": "0.00000000",
        "locked": "0.00000000"
    }, {
        "asset": "ETH",
        "free": "0.00000000",
        "locked": "0.00000000"
    }, {
        "asset": "NEO",
        "free": "0.00000000",
        "locked": "0.00000000"
    }],
    "permissions": ["SPOT"]
}
```

and extract the "asset" and "free" key with the following code:

```
  foreach ($array as $i => $values) {
        if ($i == 'balances')
{
    //show the inner array here - asset and balances
    echo "thearray";
}
}
```

How do I show the inner array where the key is balances?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "show". Do you want to insert into some HTML? Do you just want to `echo` all the elements? If you don't need to separate them, you might just `var_dump` or `print_r` the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

Question is did you try to do that on this json. It's a string, so you can't do the foreach that easily.
First you have to convert it to array with `json_decode($string, true)`, which returns associative array.

Then you can just access it by `$array['balances'`.

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$balances = $array['balances'];
var_export($balances);
```

The value is following:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'asset' => 'BTC',
    'free' => '0.00000000',
    'locked' => '0.00000000',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'asset' => 'LTC',
    'free' => '0.00000000',
    'locked' => '0.00000000',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'asset' => 'ETH',
    'free' => '0.00000000',
    'locked' => '0.00000000',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'asset' => 'NEO',
    'free' => '0.00000000',
    'locked' => '0.00000000',
  ),
)
```

`var_export` is handy, as you can immediately paste the result in the code.
If you want to get only `free` or `locked` you could use [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) call. If you need more than one column, using single `foreach` inside is advised.

Example:

```
// use array_column
$asset = array_column($balances, 'asset');
var_dump($asset);

// use foreach
$asset2 = [];
foreach ($balances as $row) {
    $asset2[] = $row['asset'];
}

var_dump($asset2);
```

Comment: Iterating to access a single key is overkill. Why not access it directly with `$array['balances']`?

Comment: Right. Too much on my mind. Thanks, will edit.

Comment: when I decode , I get the following error:Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: So you got array already. Just use key access then

Comment: Thats awesome it worked, how would I then loop that existing array and extract asset and free - sorry the n00b comments  - I tried  

    foreach ($balances as $key => $value) {

       echo "    $key => $value\n";
    }    but its giving me array errors

Comment: Try `array_column` or just loop through balances.

Comment: Thank you sir - all working perfectly now, really appreciate your help

Comment: Good luck with your next puzzles :)